# UISlider limitations in IPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, uislider

In UISlider Control if I set `"MinimumValue = 0" & "MaximimValue=2000"` then I am not able to set the exact value. On release of slider thumb image it changes the value to `+ or -   5 to10`.  My slider `width = 225px`.

For example:- if I try to set the slider value to `100` then on release of slider thumb it shows me result like `105 or 95`.

---

`Code`

```
    IBOutlet UISlider * slider;

//"Slider" Object attached using XIB(.NIB)

slider.minimumValue = 0;
slider.maximumValue = 100;

//Attached Below Method Using XIB(.NIB) with "value Changed" event.

-(IBAction)slider_Change:(id)sender;
{

//Assigning value to UITextField
   textFiled.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(((int)    (slider.value)) * 20)];
}
```

[image]

Comment: show the code that you have for the slider

Comment: @user2277872 I added code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have set your slider range to be so large each pixel on the screen is equivalent to  8.888.

```
2000 / 255 = 8.8888888889
```

To get graduations of 1 you'll need to move the slider 1/8 of a pixel (this is impossible).

Alternatives are:

1. Make the slider longer
2. Reduce the slider range
3. Use a different control [UIStepper](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStepper_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Alternatives (1) & (2) I can't do as it's requirement. Do you think any other UI way that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by @rjstelling, it seems as if you are trying to convert the value of the slider to become an integer value. I believe that the default of the slider is a double value, this would cause the value to become rounded as it is increasing, since there will not be decimal values. Unless it is a requirement, see if you can use double.

```
textFiled.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",(slider.value * 20.0)];
```

or if for some reason you'd want to restrict the level of decimal places you could go, you could do:

```
textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", slider.value * 20.0];
```

This will give you the result of a decimal like 1.5 as your answer.

You could do anything with the decimal or even do something like %1.2f, %4.3f, or even %10.4f,

those will produce results like: 0.34, 0012.446, and something extreme like 000000345.1111

Hope this helps